# Compiling Groovy with Maven and groovy-eclipse-compiler

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am having issues getting my Groovy script to compile. When I was developing the Groovy script everything worked fine, I used IntelliJ IDEA IDE for it and `groovy` command line utility to run it, with `@Grapes` and `@Grab` annotations. Now, I need to move to compiled model using Maven. Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my `pom.xml`, why the Groovy compiler complains like this:

```
[ERROR] import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
[...]
[ERROR] import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

This is my current `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.uvw</groupId>
    <artifactId>verifymetrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xyz.client</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gpars</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpars</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.4-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: One thing I would check, since you're using jcl-over-slf4j - make sure that commons-logging is not being pulled in as a transitive dependency, and exclude it if you find it. In my experience having both on the classpath can cause strange symptoms.

Comment: @user944849: The commons-logging dependency was there and I have excluded it but that did not change the compiler diagnostic output in any way.

Comment: What version of Java is Maven using?  Is it the same as that used by IntelliJ?  What version of Maven?  Also, have you tried cleaning out Maven's local artifact repo?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason `extensions` is defined as true? I have a project that uses the groovy-eclipse-compiler, I followed the directions as shown on the [groovy-eclipse-compiler plugin page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven).  Note there is no `<extensions>` flag there.

Here is the plugin configuration that works for me (using Groovy 2.2.1):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    <!-- set verbose to be true if you want lots of uninteresting messages -->
    <!-- <verbose>true</verbose> -->
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0-01</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8-01</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The `<extension>` is there because without it the compiler will not find any sources. My entire source is a single Groovy source file.